# Using powershell to Start-Job where the job runs an Angular website

Tags: powershell

I have an angular website that I want to start with powershell using the following command in powershell: Invoke-Item ng serve
But this just gives me the error: Invoke-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'serve'.

How can I run ng serve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ngopt = "serve"
Invoke-Expression "ng $ngopt"
```